# Searching List of Tuples by nth element in Python

Tags: python

So I have a list of tuples, with 3 elements each. Both the second and third elements are ints. For a value n, I need to return all the tuples that contain n as either the second or third element.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this, unfortunately. I'm sure it's not too complicated, but although there are some similar questions, I can't find any for this exact problem. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple list comprehension.  Something like:

```
[t for t in list_of_tuples if t[1] == n or t[2] == n]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with a simple `if` condition:

```
>>> lis=[('a',1,2),('b',2,2),('c',3,3),('d',3,1)]

>>> n=1

>>> [x for x in lis if n in x[1:3]]  #[1:3] returns a sublist containing 
                                     # 2 & 3 element of each tuple
[('a', 1, 2), ('d', 3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blist = [tup for tup in alist if n in tup[1:]]
```

The line above uses a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and is equivalent to:

```
blist = []
for tup in alist:
    if n in tup[1:]:
        blist.append(tup)
```

`tup[1:]` returns a new tuple, consisting of the second and third items in the three item tuple `tup`.

In hindsight [James Henstridge's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721283/james-henstridge) example seems preferable, because `t[1] == n or t[2] == n` uses the existing tuple.